# url from 'user_link' permission get error

Tags: facebook, oauth, hyperlink, profile, facebook-sdk-3.1

My website is using facebook auth to register and login with 'user_link' permission. The url given by fb is something like "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/YXNpZADpBWEhxcDBRa29....."

The problem is that the url redirects to the user's profile, when the user is my friend in facebook. In other situations the url shows an error message.

I create a competition and want user verify that users whom take part in the competition. How I can redirect users to real profile in the social network?

Comment: You can’t. Description of the `link` field explicitly says, _“The link will only resolve if the person clicking the link is logged into Facebook and is a friend of the person whose profile is being viewed.”_

Comment: I know it, but I need some way to redirect to user's profile. All social networks, which I use, has this way. I only didn't find the way in facebook. Maybe, you know the way?

Comment: There is no other way. Facebook deliberately restricted this recently, to better protect user’s privacy.

Comment: Oleg, where do you see this mentioned? Facebook clearly states this: 
"The user_link permission allows your app to access the Facebook profile URL of the person using your app. The allowed usage for this permission is to provide a way for someone who uses your app to visit a person's Facebook profile. " On the user_link page.
Link is the depreciated functionality, no?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to find a way?